# Postgres Replication with pglogical: ERROR: connection to other side has died

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication, database-administration, pglogical

Got this error (on replica) while replicating between 2 Postgres instances:

`ERROR:  connection to other side has died`

Here is the logs on the replica/subscriber:

```
    2017-09-15 20:03:55 UTC [14335-3] LOG:  apply worker [14335] at slot 7 generation 109 crashed
    2017-09-15 20:03:55 UTC [2961-1732] LOG:  worker process: pglogical apply 16384:3661733826 (PID 14335) exited with exit code 1
    2017-09-15 20:03:59 UTC [14331-2] ERROR:  connection to other side has died
    2017-09-15 20:03:59 UTC [14331-3] LOG:  apply worker [14331] at slot 2 generation 132 crashed
    2017-09-15 20:03:59 UTC [2961-1733] LOG:  worker process: pglogical apply 16384:3423246629 (PID 14331) exited with exit code 1
    2017-09-15 20:04:02 UTC [14332-2] ERROR:  connection to other side has died
    2017-09-15 20:04:02 UTC [14332-3] LOG:  apply worker [14332] at slot 4 generation 125 crashed
    2017-09-15 20:04:02 UTC [2961-1734] LOG:  worker process: pglogical apply 16384:2660030132 (PID 14332) exited with exit code 1
    2017-09-15 20:04:02 UTC [14350-1] LOG:  starting apply for subscription parking_sub
    2017-09-15 20:04:05 UTC [14334-2] ERROR:  connection to other side has died
    2017-09-15 20:04:05 UTC [14334-3] LOG:  apply worker [14334] at slot 6 generation 119 crashed
    2017-09-15 20:04:05 UTC [2961-1735] LOG:  worker process: pglogical apply 16384:394989729 (PID 14334) exited with exit code 1
    2017-09-15 20:04:06 UTC [14333-2] ERROR:  connection to other side has died
```

Logs on master/provider:

```
    2017-09-15 23:22:43 UTC [22068-5] repuser@ga-master ERROR:  got sequence entry 1 for toast chunk 1703536315 instead of seq 0
    2017-09-15 23:22:43 UTC [22068-6] repuser@ga-master LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
    2017-09-15 23:22:44 UTC [22067-5] repuser@ga-master ERROR:  got sequence entry 1 for toast chunk 1703536315 instead of seq 0
    2017-09-15 23:22:44 UTC [22067-6] repuser@ga-master LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
    2017-09-15 23:22:48 UTC [22070-5] repuser@ga-master ERROR:  got sequence entry 1 for toast chunk 1703536315 instead of seq 0
    2017-09-15 23:22:48 UTC [22070-6] repuser@ga-master LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
    2017-09-15 23:22:49 UTC [22069-5] repuser@ga-master ERROR:  got sequence entry 1 for toast chunk 1703536315 instead of seq 0
    2017-09-15 23:22:49 UTC [22069-6] repuser@ga-master LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

Config on master/provider:

```
    archive_mode = on
    archive_command = 'cp %p /data/pgdata/wal_archives/%f'
    max_wal_senders = 20
    wal_level = logical
    max_worker_processes = 100
    max_replication_slots = 100
    shared_preload_libraries = pglogical
    max_wal_size = 20GB
```

Config on the replica/subscriber:

```
    max_replication_slots = 100
    shared_preload_libraries = pglogical
    max_worker_processes = 100
    max_wal_size = 20GB
```

I'm having a total of 18 subscriptions for 18 schemas. It seemed to work fine in the beginning, but it quickly deteriorated and some subscriptions started to bounce between `down` and `replicating` statuses, with the error posted above.

### Question

What could be the possible causes? Do I need to change my Pg configurations?

Also, I noticed that when replication is going on, the CPU usage on the master/provider is pretty high.

```
    /# ps aux | sort -nrk 3,3 | head -n 5
    postgres 18180 86.4  1.0 415168 162460 ?       Rs   22:32  19:03 postgres: getaround getaround 10.240.0.7(64106) CREATE INDEX
    postgres 20349 37.0  0.2 339428 38452 ?        Rs   22:53   0:07 postgres: wal sender process repuser 10.240.0.7(49742) idle
    postgres 20351 33.8  0.2 339296 36628 ?        Rs   22:53   0:06 postgres: wal sender process repuser 10.240.0.7(49746) idle
    postgres 20350 28.8  0.2 339016 44024 ?        Rs   22:53   0:05 postgres: wal sender process repuser 10.240.0.7(49744) idle
    postgres 20352 27.6  0.2 339420 36632 ?        Rs   22:53   0:04 postgres: wal sender process repuser 10.240.0.7(49750) idle
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which was fixed by setting the: `wal_sender_timeout` config on the master/provider to 5 minutes (default is 1 minute).  It will drop the connection if it times out - this seems to have fixed the problem for me.